# How can I submit html element value to its corresponding controller in Kohana

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, kohana

I'm using kohana 2x version in my project,I've select box in view,as follows

```
<select id='type'>
<option value='type1'>Type1</option>
<option value='type2'>Type2</option>
</select>
```

By default Type1 will be selected,when page is loaded.But when user selects type2,it as to submit that value to its controller.Here problem is I'm not using form here,even though I need to submit selected value to controller without using the form and submit button.Just when user selects,Type2 from select box,I need submit its value to its controller only.How can I implement this by using Jquery and Ajax.I'm not that much good at Jquery and Ajax,even though I can manage if some answers for this question.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Mahesh.D

Comment: by the way this is not a PHP or konoha question. this is about jquery. you must add the jquery tag to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#type").change(function() {
    var input = $(this).val();

    // If you want to reload the page, use javascript to redirect
    // Or you can use ajax to send the selection dynamicly
});
```

You can find information about sending with ajax: [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)